# Android: how to see all TextAppearance styles

Tags: android, text, styles, appearance

I'm trying to style my login form, however I am having trouble getting the background of the inputs to be white.

@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Inverse works, as it displays the color white for the input title; however, for the hint text it's still black.

Is there a way to let me see all kinds of text appearance styles at once, instead of trying each style one by one? I notice there is a very long list of defined styles, but I cannot view them all together to compare.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                 android:id="@+id/textinputlayout"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                 app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Inverse">

                 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                     android:id="@+id/nameEdit"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:hint="User Name" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this.

**change `TextInputLayout`'s `LEFT-TOP` text color**

```
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
```

style code

```
<style name="text_in_layout_hint_Style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

You can do this in `.java`.

```
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.text_in_layout_hint_Style);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but is there any way (e.g. a specification table) that I can view how the styles are defined? I do not only want to change the hint text color, but also to compare which defined style looks better.

Comment: You can use more `TextInputLayout` and try different style in your xml code .

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in TextInputEditText

android:textColorHint="@color/yourColor"

Comment: Thanks for replying, but is there any way (e.g. a specification table) that I can view how the styles are defined? I do not only want to change the hint text color, but also to compare which defined style looks better.